# VisualStateManager not work with SelectionChanged in a CollectionView on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, collectionview, visualstatemanager

When I add a `SelectionChanged` function in the collection view, `VisualStateManager` does not work.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

When I add this code in `CollectionView`: `SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged"`, the `VisualStateManager` stop to work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue caused that the `SelectionChanged` could not get the selected element type like `StackLayout` or `Label`. You could use `TapGestureRecognizer` instead.

**Xaml:**

```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Accent" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="UnSelected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="10"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="MenuCollection"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Infos}"
            SelectionChanged="MenuCollection_OnSelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="15"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="15" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Info> Infos { get; set; }
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Infos = new ObservableCollection<Info>
    {
        new Info(){ Title="A"},
        new Info(){ Title="B"},
        new Info(){ Title="B"},
        new Info(){ Title="C"},
        new Info(){ Title="D"}
    };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    StackLayout lastElementSelected;
    private void MenuCollection_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {      

     

    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lastElementSelected != null)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(lastElementSelected, "UnSelected");

        VisualStateManager.GoToState((StackLayout)sender, "Selected");

        lastElementSelected = (StackLayout)sender;
    }
}
public class Info
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]